# sed + count words on field 3

Tags: sed

I used the following awk in order to count all words that appears in field 4

```
  awk '{print $4}'  file | awk '{print NF}' | grep -c 1
```

How we can to the same in sed?

Example of file:

```
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2
 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
```

From file sed should return the results 3 (three words on field 4)

yael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `awk` is quite inefficient. Try this:

```
awk '$4{c++}END{print c}' file
```

Why do you want it in `sed`, BTW? This is what `awk` does well. If you really want it in `sed`, I guess something like this:

```
sed '/^\s*\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*\s*$/d' file | wc -l
```

`awk` explanation: In every line where fourth field is non-null, increment c. At the end, print c.

`sed` explanation: delete each line which matches the regexp. Then with `wc` count the lines of the `sed` output. The regexp basically says there can be maximum of two whitespace groups in the line, not counting initial and final ones, which then means there can be at most 3 fields in the line.

Answer (score 0):

`cut` can also be used:

```
cut -f 5 -d' ' file | wc -w
```

Select the 5. column (the first one is empty due to the leading blank). The delimiter is a blank.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/ *[^ ]*/&/4;t;d;' file | sed -n '$='
```